# Kuberntes SSL for Service of Type LoadBalancer

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am deploying a Socket.IO and NodeJs based application on Kubernetes. I found that with the following configuration of Service I can maintain client stickiness very easily,

```
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: my-service
      labels:
        app: my-service
    spec:
      replicas: 3
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: my-service
        spec:
          containers:
            - image: gcr.io/app_name/my-service:latest
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              name: my-service
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8080
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: my-service
      annotations:
        traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness: "true"
      labels:
        app: my-service
    spec:
      type: LoadBalancer
      sessionAffinity: "ClientIP"
      ports:
        - name: my-service
          port: 80
          protocol: TCP
          targetPort: 4000
      selector:
        app: my-service
```

Now, I am stuck with adding **SSL Certs**. I am not able to get a documentation or resource to add **SSL Certs** for **Service** of **Type** **LoadBalancer**. Is it Possible? if it is then, how can I dot it?

If it is not possible at all is there any other way? I am using GKE on GCP.
Can anyone help me with this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks kind of weird as you mention traefik in your annotations. Still, managing cert for this case is almost impossible≥ It would have to be supported on cloud provider level based on annotations cause there is no explicit way to bound tls certificate with particular service/port, not to mention automated certificates like with cert-manager/ingress.

To achieve that you should use some kind of API gateway / ingress controller, that can handle this for you instead of exposing your service directly, or implement TLS support in your application.

Comment: why traefik is weird? and so it's not possible for Type LoadBalancer. I wanted to support web sockets. Tried everything but could not achieve it, in Kubernetes in GCP. Any other solution for this implementation? My project is in Nodejs, Socket.IO.

Comment: why would you have traefik annotation on service which you want to expose directly with LoadBalancer?

Comment: For the socket session stickiness. Yup, just saw it has been deprecated.

Comment: you're mixing two things. Although you can actually expose service via LoadBalancer and Traefik Ingress at the same time, one has nothing to to with the other. Traefik annotations will work for traefik-ingress, not for LoadBalancer.

Comment: Okay then what could be the best approach in case of an application using Socket.Io, NodeJs, where I need to maintain the stickiness. Do you have any reference?